# Connection errors to remote rabbitmq instance using SSL when using pika python module

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to connect to a remote rabbitmq instance using SSL. I decided to use the pika module, as it seems to be the most widely used module. I have the cacert from the remote server, and am not failing the connection if there is no peer cert. I am also using a self signed cert, and not verifying the cert on the server end. Despite all of this, I keep getting connection errors. I know I am probably just configuring the parameters incorrectly, but I've been spinning my wheels on this problem for a few days now. How can I configure the parameters properly to connect to my rabbitmq instance?

Here is my rabbitmq server configuration

```
  {rabbit,
    [
      { tcp_listeners, [ 5672 ] },
      { ssl_listeners, [ 5671 ] },
      { ssl_options,  [
        { certfile,   "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cert.pem" },
        { keyfile,    "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/key.pem" },
        { cacertfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cacert.pem" },
        { verify,   verify_none },
        { fail_if_no_peer_cert, false } ] },
      {default_user, <<"guest">>},
      {loopback_users, []}
    ]
```

and here is the code i am trying

```
server = "server"
port = 5671
caCert = "./cacert.pem"
context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile="./cacert.pem")
ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(context, server)
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=server, port=port, ssl_options=ssl_options)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
```

I expect to get 0 errors when I run this code, but I keep getting some form of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

Answer (score 1):

This actually ended up being a firewall issue.